# Saving Excel table as html WITHOUT style

Tags: html, css, excel, tablelayout

I am trying to save an Excel table as an HTML file.
I have prepared an external CSS file which I want to use that contains my styles.
However, Excel saves the table as HTML with several style options which, as they are applied in-code to specific elements, override my CSS file.

Is there a way to save the table from Excel without the style elements?

Specifically, the element I'm looking to get rid of is "table-layout: fixed;" which hampers my attempts to control the table width.

Thank you.

Comment: then just delete the `table-layout: fixed;` code from the file

Answer (score 0):

you could easily do this with some javascript, import the html file in a webpage and just add this to your script and add it when needed.

```
var e = document.getElementByTagName('table')[0]; //assuming the table is the 1st one to appear
// or get by id with document.getElementByID('IDhere')
e.removeAttribute("style");
```

or with multiple tables that have the attribute

```
var e = document.getElementByTagName('table');
for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e[i].removeAttribute("style");
}
```

Comment: If I open my script, I could just as well simply copy-paste the CSS.
I am trying to avoid the need to open the script so that I can just save the HTML and put it on the server without the need to edit it.